# Hibernate locked Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hibernate

I want to hibernate a locked Windows XP. How to enable this function in lock screen? Or can it be programmed to hardware power button (when lock screen is active)?

(By "locked" I mean after pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del, then Enter. Then it normally wants to enter the user password to unlock the computer. Now the computer cannot be turned off without losing data, but I think it should be possible to hibernate it. If it was a notebook, I would simply close the cover to hibernate it. But I want it on a desktop PC in the office.)

Answer (score 3):

Set your PC's physical power button to be Hibernate, then you can just push it to initiate the Hibernation while at the lock screen (or wherever).

You can do this via `Control Panel --> Performance and Maintenance --> Power Options --> Advanced Tab`.

In there should be the *"When I press the power button on my computer:"* option, and you should be able to set it to Hibernate (assuming Hibernation is enabled and working on the system).

Comment: And if you would like to do it remotely: http://superuser.com/questions/5857/can-i-remotely-hibernate-a-computer

Comment: Yes, remote hiberation can also help me.